globally declaring method on Function.prototype that returns the same function signature
I'm migrating some code to TS, and the original code is using a library that adds a method to Function.prototype. Since it is used in a lot of places, I can't simply replace that and would like to define a global that let me compile the project in the meanwhile.
Right now I added a global.d.ts with the following code:
declare interface Function {
    for(): Function;
}

But of course that doesn't work, as every method has a different signature (params/return type).
The library is used as following (example)
class FrontClient {
    constructor(baseUrl: string, sessionId: string) {
        this.addPipeline(this._addHeaders.for(this));
    }

    private _addHeaders(request: HttpRequest, next: (() => Promise<Response>)): Promise<Response> {
        ....
    }

    private addPipeline(pipeline: ((request: HttpRequest, next: (() => Promise<Response>)) => Promise<Response>)): void {
        ...
    }
}

As is, this doesn't compile because of this expression: this._addHeaders.for(this). Also, please note that this is a simple example. The library is also used to bind functions to events and since it always returns the same bounded method, it can be used to remove listeners without having to store the bounded method. That's why the refactoring will take some time.
How can I modify what I have in my global.d.ts to cater for any method signature?
Thanks!

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes!, thanks, I didn't know you could use "this" as argument name to reference the method ref (in this case). It looks like c# extension methods.

See the answer to the linked q/a above. Effectively it would be nice if you could use the polymorphic this type to represent "the current function type", but TS doesn't do what you want there. The workaround is to use a generic this parameter instead.
